# How to deploy war file in amazon AWS apache tomcat and access using domain name

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee

I want to access the application through the domain name. For Example www.xyz.com/login.jsp. For the same i have placed my web app in ROOT folder of the apache tomcat in AWS, and i can access the app.

But i want to deploy the war file and access the application. If i put the war file in ROOT folder i am not able to access the application. Cab you please help me out on this like where to put the war file in apache tomcat folder in AWS

and if i have 2 application like client application and webservcie application. Where to deploy these 2 appliation so that whenever request comes from client it should call the webservice and gives the response back.

Can you please help me out in configuring my application in AWS apache tomcat.